# How to use R to sort two groups based on shared elements?

Tags: r

I have 2 groups (alpha & beta) and want to use R to get 3 lists of the elements present in 1. only alpha, 2. only beta, 3. both groups. So basically a Venn-diagramm in list-form. Here an example:

```
group   color
alpha   red
alpha   blue
alpha   black
alpha   white
alpha   orange
beta    green
beta    white
beta    purple
beta    yellow
beta    black
```

As a result, the lists should be something like:

```
alpha: red, blue, orange 
beta: green, purple, yellow
both: black, white
```

Assuming I have the data saved in a (tab-separated) .txt-file or a .csv-file (e.g. FILE.txt), how would I have to import/preprocess the data and how could I get the elements sorted as described? Are there any packages that need to be installed beforehand? Sorry, I know some steps likely seem obvious, but my R-skills are somewhat limited.

Thanks a lot for the help!

p.s. Not essential, but "nice to have": What if I wanted to sort 3 different groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setdiff` and `intersect`:

```
y <- split(x$color, x$group)
z <- list(setdiff(y[[1]], y[[2]]), setdiff(y[[2]], y[[1]]))
names(z) <- names(y)
z[["both"]] <- intersect(y[[1]], y[[2]])
z
#$alpha
#[1] "red"    "blue"   "orange"
#
#$beta
#[1] "green"  "purple" "yellow"
#
#$both
#[1] "black" "white"
```

Data:

```
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="group   color
alpha   red
alpha   blue
alpha   black
alpha   white
alpha   orange
beta    green
beta    white
beta    purple
beta    yellow
beta    black")
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick help, this works very nicely. Just in cases others are reading this later, I now also figured out how to export the result into a .csv-file: zdata<-do.call("rbind", z) and then write.csv(zdata, "FILENAME.csv")